# Persistent Menu Across Wordpress Network

Tags: wordpress

I've got a multsite setup for a network of agricultural companies but I need to have a persistent menu to access the different pages, ideally with nested access to sub pages.

For example: I would like to have something like this in my footer without having to hardcode the links in some kind of block. How can I expose the entire network in the menu edit page?

```
Site 1
-Page 1
-Page 2
Site 2
-Page 1
-Page 2
Site 3
-Page 1
-Page 2
```

Comment: If you're a Wordpress dev you could probably pull it off by using the code for sharing sidebars located at http://ekdhl.net/blog/2012/10/19/sharing-information-between-wordpress-multi-user-blogswebsites/ and then using the menu widget. The reason you need to be a dev is that the widget may need modification to get the right menu, since it may use system variables dependent on the current blog.

Comment: But if you don't feel up to it, you could always just make a static menu and put it in a text widget in a shared sidebar. That way it would still be editable, and you wouldn't have to work for it.

Comment: I'm intending on having custom graphics to indicate the different stores so I am looking at making a custom post type for that in which case the referenced plugin in this post should solve the problem. So - THANKS for the tip! :) Care to offer your "first comment" as an answer so I can give you credit for the answer?

Comment: I did now - thank you and glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're a Wordpress dev you could probably pull it off by using the code for sharing sidebars located at [ekdhl.net/blog/2012/10/19/](http://ekdhl.net/blog/2012/10/19/)… and then using the menu widget. The reason you need to be a dev is that the widget may need modification to get the right menu, since it may use system variables dependent on the current blog.